# Defining own Ord for a data type

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I am attempting to make some data structures to solve a graph puzzle. I am trying to define an edge's comparison criteria, but I am not sure how. So far:

```
data Edge = Edge (Set String) Bool
```

How can I 'inform' the compiler that I want edges to be declared equal if they have identical sets of strings, and not have equality have anything to do with the boolean value?

Comment: dont forget about the `deriving` keyword!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Although I'm not sure why you want to ignore the boolean value (I'm curious), to do so you'll have to define your own `Eq` instance; the default one won't work, as it compares every field.  Luckily, this is easy:

```
instance Eq Edge where
  (Edge s1 _) == (Edge s2 _) = s1 == s2
```

If you want to be able to order edges, and you want the ordering to compare just the sets too, your implementation is very similar:

```
instance Ord Edge where
  (Edge s1 _) `compare` (Edge s2 _) = s1 `compare` s2
```

Each type class defines a certain set of methods which need to be implemented; `Eq` requires `==` or `/=`, and `Ord` requires `<=` or `compare`.  (To find out which functions are required and which are optional, you can check the docs.)

Comment: I am ignoring the boolean because I am working with a directed graph. However, because the only edges that are important to me are ones that are are bidirectional between both nodes. I am using the boolean as a "reciprocated" field, so I can get rid of any directed edges that don't have an equivalent returning edge. I can then filter on that boolean to create an undirected graph.

It's ugly but I can't think of anything else on short notice.

Answer (score 17):

```
import Data.Set

data Edge = Edge (Set String) Bool deriving Show

instance Eq Edge where
    (Edge a _) == (Edge b _) = a == b

instance Ord Edge where
    compare (Edge a _) (Edge b _) = compare a b
```