# Haskell, inserting into an ordered list

Tags: list, haskell, nodes

I am beginning to learn about Haskell and have been closely following the guides at http://learnyouahaskell.com and the documentation at https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_work_on_lists. I have been working with nodes and binary trees as of late and have run into a problem that I cannot seem to figure out the correct syntax for.

If I have an ordered list of nodes:

```
[(2 , Nil, Nil), (4, Nil, Nil), (10, Nil, Nil)]
```

And I want to insert a new node `(3, Nil, Nil)` into the list so that it could be represented as:

```
[(2, Nil, Nil), (3, Nil, Nil),(4, Nil, Nil), (10, Nil, Nil)]
```

What is the most elegant solution to do this? From what I have read [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_work_on_lists) it looks as if you have to split the list in two parts once you detect the correct position but as a beginner im not sure how to do this. Obviously the pseudo code would be something a long the lines of `For every Node in the list, compare its number value versus the count value of the new Node . Once this value is greater than  or equal to the current index, split the list into two parts (a and b) and then combine the list in this order a ++ [newElement] ++ b`.

In my mind (again, at a beginner level) when trying to implement this it would look like:

sortedInsert

Comment: you can get this working if you have split - but if you don't have it (yet) you basically replaced this problem with another (probably equal difficult for you) problem - have you tried a basic recursive approach with patter-matching on the input list yet? This way it's rather easy to do - do it and show the code you get if you run into trouble

Answer (score 3):

Well the pattern-matching is the usual one.

This is the general case:

```
insertOrdered :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insertOrdered a [] = [a]
insertOrdered a bs'@(b:bs)
  | a <= b     = a : bs'
  | otherwise = b : insertOrdered a bs
```

your turn: replace the undefined with some code of yours ;)

---

#### Note

- Whatever `Nil` here is you have to either make it an instance of `Ord` or you have to change the function to directly deal only with the first component of the tuple

I choose to just use:

```
data Nil = Nil
         deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

and it will work as is:

```
λ> let xs = [(2 , Nil, Nil), (4, Nil, Nil), (10, Nil, Nil)]
λ> insertOrdered (3,Nil,Nil) xs
[(2,Nil,Nil),(3,Nil,Nil),(4,Nil,Nil),(10,Nil,Nil)]
```

but maybe you have to change this for you like this:

```
insertOrdered :: Ord a => (a,b,c) -> [(a,b,c)] -> [(a,b,c)]
insertOrdered x [] = undefined
insertOrdered x@(a,_,_) ((a',_,_):ys)
  | a <= a'   = undefined
  | otherwise = undefined -- probably something with insertOrdered?
```

Comment: I had never seen the @ before in `bs'@(b:bs)` - looks like it provides two different patterns for the same thing?

Comment: @Carsten, how would I reference the list if I am using `((a',_,_):ys)`? Like what would I do to return the list combined? something ++ [new list] ++ bs?

Comment: that's what the `bs'@...` is for - the `bs'` represents the the complete pattern after so you don't have to reconstruct it - it's really just the same as the solution I gave - I gave the `x` and the `bs'` to make it more comfortable for you

Comment: I was surprised to see your function not look like `insertOrdered x = go where ...`, which seemed like an easy improvement to me since you never need to pass a new x. Am I missing some style or good-taste reason why this is worse?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean - IMO you gain nothing here - yes you can use `x` inside your `go` without redefining it but if you want to use patter-matching you just have to do it with `go` in the `where`... maybe it's a matter of tast - why don't you add your answer and let the OP decide?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting with simple lists, like lists of Nums. Here's a function that inserts a member in a list, as long as the elements can be compared:

```
insertOrdered :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]   -- Ord means the elements of the list can be ordered
insertOrdered item [] = [item]              -- Empty list, return list with a single argument
insertOrdered item (first:ls)               -- Split list between first element and the rest of it
    | item <= first = item : first : ls     -- Append our item at the start and merge everything
    | otherwise = first : (insertOrdered item ls)   -- Merge the first element with the result of calling this again
```

You can test it immediatly with something like:

```
insertOrdered 1 [0, 2, 3]    -- [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now that it works for the simple case, you can think about your harder one. That means telling Haskell that you type can be ordered and how to do it, which you can learn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065954/defining-your-own-ord-for-a-data-type-haskell).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion looks a lot like Carsten's, but I think it's a bit nicer to use an auxiliary `go` function to avoid having to pass around the `x` argument manually so often:

```
insertOrdered :: Ord a => x -> [a] -> [a]
insertOrdered x = go where
  go [] = [x]
  go all@(y:ys) | x < y = x : all
                | otherwise = y : go ys
```

Comment: From an efficiency standpoint, it's usually better to pull out constant arguments only if there are at least two of them. It's not likely to make a huge difference though.